# JPA/hibernate sorted collection @OrderBy vs @Sort

Tags: hibernate, jpa, collections, sql-order-by, sorting

I would like to have a collection of child objects (here cat-kitten example) that are ordered.  And keep their order on adding of new elements.

```
@Entity 
public class Cat {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("name ASC")
  private List<Kitten> kittens;

  public void setKittens(List<Kitten> kittens) { this.kittens = kittens; }
  public List<Kitten> getKittens() { return kittens; } 
}
```

When I do `cat.getKittens.add(newKitten)` the order by name will be broken.

Is it possible to let hibernate do the work of keeping the collection always ordered? By using the [@Sort hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Sort.html) annotation?
@Sort has the disadvantage that it forces you to implement Comparable interface ...
What would be the right 'pure JPA' way to do that? Saving everything to DB and reloading it?
Makes it sense to combine @OrderBy and @Sort?

**Update**
Solution up to now is to combine @OrderBy and @Sort. @OrderBy leads to a `ORDER BY` clause in the generated SQL which is better for performance (I assume that java is "sorting" again on inserting into the sorted container, but that should be much faster because the elements are already sorted)
@Sort together with an implemented `Comparable` interface leads to a always sorted container. Note that I use now `SortedSet` instead of `List`. Here the updated Code:

```
@Entity 
public class Cat {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("name ASC")
  @Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
  private SortedSet<Kitten> kittens;

  public void setKittens(SortedSet<Kitten> kittens) { this.kittens = kittens; }
  public SortedSet<Kitten> getKittens() { return kittens; } 
}
```

Comment: Deprecated since Hibernate 4.3.0 see: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8164

Comment: Use `@SortNatural` and `@SortComparator`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-sorted-set

Comment: I wouldn't assume that a pre-sorted list is faster to add to a TreeSet. I would expect the opposite, since an inorder sequence requires more tree rebalancing. You're better off using `@SortNatural` or `@OrderBy`, not both.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to avoid non-standard annotations, you could make `kittens` use some sorted `Collection` implementation. This would ensure that `kittens` is always in sorted order. Something like this:

```
@Entity 
public class Cat {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("name ASC")
  private SortedSet<Kitten> kittens = new TreeSet<>();
}
```

Note that this approach also requires `Kitten` to implement `Comparable` (alternatively, you could pass a `Comparator` to your `TreeSet` constructor). Also, I'm using a `Set` because I'm not aware of any standard sorted `List` implementation and I'm assuming the `Cat` does not have any clones in its litter =p.

**Update:**
I'm not sure how picky Hibernate is with its getter/setter definitions, but with EclipseLink I've been able to remove a setter entirely and wrap the `List` returned by my getter in a `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` call. I then defined special methods for modifying the collection. You could do the same thing and force callers to use an add method that inserts elements in sorted order. If Hibernate complains about not having the getter/setter, maybe you could change the access modifier? I guess it comes down to how far you're willing to go to avoid non standard dependencies.

Comment: Could it be better to use `SortedSet` interface? Because the initialization with `= new TreeSet<>()` will be replaced when generated by hibernate. `Set` leads to `PersistentSet` which uses internally a `LinkedHashSet` (you lost `TreeSet` and keep just the insert order, correct?). A `SortedSet` will be replaced by a `PersistentSortedSet` that internally uses, yes finally, a `TreeSet`... Note: using `SortedSet` forces you to specify `@Sort` annotation :-/

Comment: Ah...I wasn't aware Hibernate would do that. I've used a similar approach with EclipseLink, but I'm afraid I'm not as familiar with Hibernate

Comment: Updated my answer with another idea. Not the cleanest solution, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Thanks! In the trade off between 'pure JPA' and 'less code' I choose 'less code' in this case. Might be different for other projects...

Comment: I've had success following the approach outlined in @DannyMo's footnote - you can make it very painless and laconic (code-wise) by adding Google Guava to the bunch (for the sorting).

Comment: If anyone is lost trying to accomplish this with the latest version of Hibernate, see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42170280/1988326

Answer (score 23):

The latest version of Hibernate uses new annotations to accomplish this:

```
@SortNatural
@OrderBy("name ASC")
private SortedSet<Kitten> kittens = new TreeSet<>();
```

There are two parts to this:

1. The `@OrderBy` annotation specifies that an `order by` clause should be added to the database query when fetching the related records.
2. The `@SortNatural` annotation assumes that `Kitten` implements the `Comparable` interface and uses that information when constructing the `TreeSet` instance. Note that you can replace this with the `@SortComparator` annotation, which allows you to specify a `Comparator` class that will be passed to the `TreeSet` constructor.

See documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-sorted-set

Comment: this worked for me
```
@Setter
    @Getter
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, mappedBy = "trending")
    @SortNatural
    @OrderBy("creationDate desc ")
    private List<Tweet> tweets;
```

Comment: Using a `SortedSet` with `@SortNatural` and `@OrderBy` does not work using Hibernate 6 (With Spring Boot 3.1.x).  I gives an exception `Collection is both sorted and ordered`.

Answer (score 0):

For Hibernate 6, the recommended way is to use a `SortedSet` for the collection, annotated with `@SortNatural` or `@SortComparator` according to the docs.

From [the user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-set):

> An ordered set does not perform any sorting in-memory. If an element is added after the collection is loaded, the collection would need to be refreshed to re-order the elements. For this reason, ordered sets are not recommended - if the application needs ordering of the set elements, a sorted set should be preferred.

You cannot combine `@SortNatural` or `@SortComparator` with `@OrderedBy`. This throws an exception `Collection '...' is both sorted and ordered`.