# Is it possible to use the JPA @OrderBy annotation to sort in a case-insensitive way?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I’m using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and MySQL 5.5.  I want to use the @OrderBy annotation to sort a set in one of my entities …

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "classroom", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval=true)
@OrderBy(“name”)
private Set<User> roster;
```

However, I would like the set to be sorted in a case-insensitive way, or at least sort everything according to the lower-case of the "name" attribute.  Is this possible with JPA?  I can upgrade my JPA and Hibernate versions if this solves my problem.

Comment: This relies in Hibernate rather than pure JPA, but you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871765/jpa-hibernate-sorted-collection-orderby-vs-sort

Comment: Another variation could be defining a calculated column in the database like `lower(name)`, define a property for it (make it read-only), and order by it. Then again not very JPA-ish.

Comment: Regarding the first link you posted, where he does the case insensitive ordering?  Making my variable a SortedSet doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Make your entity implement `Comparable` and implement as you wish...

Comment: I don't want to do that and that's not my question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to stick with the standard JPA annotations and not go with a provider (Hibernate) specific ones it's not possible.  However, by making use of a TreeSet with your own comparator you can achieve the same behavior.

eg:

```
Set<User> roster = new TreeSet<User>(new MyComparator());
```