# How to write @OrderBy annotation for the outer joined table field to sort collection using SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

There are 3 tables. There is the variable of "relatedCameraSet" need to order by "camera.name" using SQL, but the field of "camera.name" is not in table of "RelatedCamera", is in the outer joined table of "Camera". The following annotation of @OrderBy doesn't work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MICRO_MAP")
public class MicroMap { //main table
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mapId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("camera.name") //OrderBy the field of "name" in Camera table 
    private Set<RelatedCamera> relatedCameraSet;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<RelatedCamera> getRelatedCameraSet() {
        return relatedCameraSet;
    }

    public void setRelatedCameraSet(Set<RelatedCamera> relatedCameraSet) {
        this.relatedCameraSet = relatedCameraSet;
    }    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "RELATED_CAMERA")
public class RelatedCamera {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "MAP_ID")
    private String mapId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAMERA_ID", referencedColumnName="id",nullable = true)
    private Camera camera;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMapId() {
        return mapId;
    }

    public void setMapId(String mapId) {
        this.mapId = mapId;
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
    }    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMERA")
public class Camera {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

How to write @OrderBy annotation in order to sort collection by camera name using SQL?

Thanks alot!

Comment: look to first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871765/jpa-hibernate-sorted-collection-orderby-vs-sort it seems what you want, good luck :)

Comment: Sorry, my question is totally different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871765/jpa-hibernate-sorted-collection-orderby-vs-sort. In that case, the field to be OrderedBy in main table. In my case, the field to be OrderedBy in the outer joined table.

Comment: There is any possible to sort the collection just by SQL, not implement Comparable interface with passing a Comparator?

Comment: I guess it isn't possible do it just by SQL, you have implement Comparable interface in your RelatedCamera class...

Comment: Now i think it is a bug in Hibernate, becuase it's OK to use "camera.name" in the HQL of " from RelatedCamera where mapId=1 order by camera.name", and it's not OK to use "camera.name" in @OrderBy annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I researched your problem and found that from the API docs: 
[Hibernate JPA 2.1 API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html)

> The property or field name must correspond to that of a persistent property or field of the associated class or embedded class within it.

that's why it is not possible do it by just OrderBy, you can order only by camera_id column from MicroMap class.

What you want can be done by @Sort and implementing Comparable interface or by specifying a Comparator:

[Annotation Type Sort](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Sort.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for doing research for me. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @luckysohu you're welcome! could you accept my answer as solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Now i realize it's impossible to do by @OrderBy, and i think it's not efficient to to do by implementing Comparable interface or specifying a Comparator, because it will take two steps to get job done, the step one is query from DB, the step two is sorting in memory. It's efficient to get sorted collection just by SQL.

In order to get high efficiency, i have to change the class of MicroMap as following:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MICRO_MAP")
public class MicroMap {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mapId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
//    @OrderBy("camera.name") //OrderBy the field of "name" in Camera table, But JPA doesn't support
//    private Set<RelatedCamera> relatedCameraSet;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and add a method in DAO or Service class.

```
public List<RelatedCamera> getRelatedCamera(Long mapId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<RelatedCamera> list = session.createQuery(" from RelatedCamera where mapId="+mapId+" order by camera.name").list();
    return list;
}
```