# Retain entity nested collection ordering after updating it

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I defined a schema where one entity `Event` has a many-to-many relationship with another entity `Person`.

On the side of the `Event`, I sorted the collection of `Person` according to one of its property (`name` in my example).

It works well when I query a fresh instance of `Event`, but it doesn't work after the same entity has been modified.
Instead, it will retain the order of insertion, which is not correct.

Here the `Event`:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    private LocalDate occursAt;

    @ManyToMany
    @OrderBy("name")
    private Set<Person> participants = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));

}
```

Here's the `Person`:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "participants")
    @OrderBy("name")
    private Set<Event> events = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Event::getName));

}
```

Here's the method responsible to add new participants to an event:

```
@PostMapping("/{event}/participants/{participant}")
public PublicEvent addParticipant(@PathVariable UUID event, @PathVariable UUID participant) {
    var originalEvent = eventRepo.getReferenceById(event);
    var originalPerson = personRepo.getReferenceById(participant);

    originalPerson.getEvents().add(originalEvent);
    originalEvent.getParticipants().add(originalPerson);

    personRepo.save(originalPerson);

    return PublicEvent.from(originalEvent);
}
```

Here's a test where the last assertion fails because of the unexpected behavior:

```
@Test
void addParticipant_addOne_oneMore() {
    var event = et.createEventWithParticipantsAs("add-one@email.com");
    var lastGuestRef = new AtomicReference<Person>();

    up.asUser("add-one@email.com", () -> {
        var lastGuest = new Person().setName("Bob");
        lastGuestRef.set(personRepo.save(lastGuest));
    });

    var lastGuest = lastGuestRef.get();

    var response = testRest.perform(
            POST,
            "/events/%s/participants/%s".formatted(event.getId(), lastGuest.getId()),
            null,
            PublicEvent.class,
            up.header("add-one@email.com")
    );

    assertThat(response.status()).isEqualTo(200);
    var participants = new ArrayList<>(event.getParticipants());
    participants.add(lastGuest);
    // Java and PostgreSQL lexicographical order is not quite the same, but it does not matter here
    participants.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
    assertThat(response.body().participants().size()).isEqualTo(event.getParticipants().size() + 1);
    assertThat(response.body().participants()).isEqualTo(PersonCtrl.PublicPerson.from(participants));
}
```

Note that I'm using some custom functions that to create a user and store it in the `SecurityContextManager`. Hopefully, the test logic should still be clear to the reader.

The expected result is:

```
[PublicPerson[id=05572a20-f82c-4d16-81f3-f41ccd45ac89, name=Alexandre],
    PublicPerson[id=955f6354-7699-4b18-8825-80808bacf7e4, name=Benoit],
    PublicPerson[id=8f1ec49d-530c-4ea8-bb20-555f4119d96c, name=Bob],
    PublicPerson[id=a7fb90ba-06f4-432e-92c9-65c968d4b34c, name=Coraline],
    PublicPerson[id=ca4d0019-9c3b-4ed7-a446-8bfb7f9ba58a, name=Denise],
    PublicPerson[id=e20da141-304a-4baa-9cbf-bc9a77435869, name=Eleonore],
    PublicPerson[id=6bd739c6-c977-4567-95c8-f8ddd60dff08, name=Frank]]
```

But the actual result is:

```
[PublicPerson[id=05572a20-f82c-4d16-81f3-f41ccd45ac89, name=Alexandre],
    PublicPerson[id=955f6354-7699-4b18-8825-80808bacf7e4, name=Benoit],
    PublicPerson[id=a7fb90ba-06f4-432e-92c9-65c968d4b34c, name=Coraline],
    PublicPerson[id=ca4d0019-9c3b-4ed7-a446-8bfb7f9ba58a, name=Denise],
    PublicPerson[id=e20da141-304a-4baa-9cbf-bc9a77435869, name=Eleonore],
    PublicPerson[id=6bd739c6-c977-4567-95c8-f8ddd60dff08, name=Frank],
    PublicPerson[id=8f1ec49d-530c-4ea8-bb20-555f4119d96c, name=Bob]]
```

I understand that the problem comes from Hibernate replacing my `TreeSortedSet` with a `PersistentSet` and only applying `@OrderBy` upon retrieval of an entity.

Now I wonder, how can I retrieve the entity with the nested collection in the expected order (which respects `@OrderBy`) ?

Comment: Add `@Sort(comparator = Comparator.comparing(Event::getName))` which will retain the sort order, however it will be less performant as it now will use a `SortedSet` instead of a `RegularSet`.

Answer (score 0):

By searching the annotation `@Sort` mentioned by the user "M. Deinum" in the comments, I stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170280/7752551, which compares `@OrderBy` and `@SortNatural`.

The former fails my use case because Hibernate `@OrderBy` annotation implies a corresponding `ORDER BY` clause at SQL level. Furthermore, it doesn't care about any manipulation at Java level. Thus, any java code touching said list must handle its order itself. And it's particularly bothersome as lexicographical order of Java and SQL are not the same (think of accentuated letters).

The second option is to use `SortNatural` who uses the interface `Comparable` implemented by the nested entity. This solution means that sorting is dealt with entirely at the Java level. It's less efficient, but it's consistent at least.
A comparable option is `@SortComparator`, which behaves exactly the same way, but requires providing a `Comparator` instead of implementing `Comparable` with the nested entity.